# Parse XML into Table from Comma Seperated Values

Tags: xml, forms

I am parsing XML using form data. The user enters dates on the frontend, and based on the dates provided it gives back results. The results however need converting into a table, right now they are comma separated. I have found a lot of articles regarding SQL tables using XML but this is not coming from an SQL table, and I can't get it working.

The results come back like this:

> 10/10/17,10/11/17,10/12/17***,10/13/17***,10/14/17***,10/15/17***,10/16/17,10/17/17,10/18/17,10/19/17***,10/20/17***,10/21/17***,10/22/17***,10/23/17,10/24/17,10/25/17;San Clemente,275,275,350,XX,XX,XX,275,275,275,350,XX,XX,XX,275,275,275;Anacapa,275,275,350,XX,XX,XX,275,275,275,350,XX,XX,XX,275,275,275;Santa Cruz,250,250,XX,XX,XX,XX,XX,XX,XX,XX,XX,XX,XX,250,250,250;Santa Barbara,275,275,XX,XX,XX,XX,275,275,275,XX,XX,XX,XX,XX,XX,XX;Santa Catalina,XX,XX,XX,XX,XX,XX,395,395,395,495,XX,XX,XX,XX,395,395;San Nicolas,XX,330,XX,XX,XX,XX,330,330,330,XX,XX,XX,XX,330,330,330;

I need it to look more like this:

```
             10/10/17   10/11/17   10/12/17
San Clemente   275        275        350
Anacapa        275        275        350
```

Etc; obviously the table would be a lot bigger than this.

My current PHP call to retrieve the XML from the form is:

```
<?php

$xml = file_get_contents("http://99.999.999.999:81/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=Front_Desk&-lay=WebRoomQuery&-findany&-script=RSWebQueryPSOS&-script.param=snug,".$_GET['start'].'');

echo $xml;

    SELECT * FROM 

?>
```

I tried this:

```
<?php

$xml = file_get_contents("http://99.999.999.999:81/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=Front_Desk&-lay=WebRoomQuery&-findany&-script=RSWebQueryPSOS&-script.param=snug,".$_GET['start'].'');

echo $xml;

    SELECT * FROM 

Declare @Ids varchar(50) Set @Ids = ',1,2,3,5,4,6,7,98,234,'

Select * from sometable
 where Charindex(','+cast(tableid as varchar(8000))+',', @Ids) > 0      
?>
```

But it doesn't work and honestly i'm not sure what i'm doing entirely :/. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with the same problem, this is how I did it:

```
echo "<table>\n<tr><td>".str_replace(array(",", ";"), array("</td><td>", "</td></tr>\n<tr><td>"), $xml)."</td></tr></table>";
```